# Fast Perl Parser Modules?

Tags: perl, parsing, perl-module

At my work I wrote a little parser for C-like expressions in one of our in-house Perl tools. I initially chose Parse::RecDescent because of its extreme ease of use and straightforward grammar syntax, but I'm finding that it's excessively slow (which is corroborated by general opinion found on the web). It's safe to assume that the grammar of the expressions is no more complicated than that of C.

What are the fastest (but still with a straightforward and uncumbersome grammar format) lexxer/parser modules for the use case of thousands of simple expressions (I'd guestimate the median length is 1 token, mean is 2 or so, and max is 30)? Additionally, thanks to unsavory IT choices, it must work in Perl 5.8.8 and it and any non-core dependencies must be pure Perl.

Answer (score 1):

[Parse::Eyapp](https://metacpan.org/release/Parse-Eyapp) looks like satysfying [5.8.8, pure perl and dependency requirements](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/P/Parse-Eyapp.html?oncpan=1&distmat=1&version=1.182). As for speed, it claims LALR parsers, which must be faster than recursive descent. A grammar for expressions is given in [the doc](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Parse-Eyapp/lib/Parse/Eyapp/Parse.pod#An-Example-of-Default-Action:-Translator-from-Infix-to-Postfix). Hope it helps.